# Why are in which reference variables and pointers point to is not stored in the stack itself but needs a heap

Tags: memory, heap-memory

Why is it needed to introduce a new data structure to handle what ref vars and pointers point to. Isn't the stack enough.

I know 100% what a stack is.

As for heaps all I recall from 12 years + is that they are tree structs (sorry for minimal revision & due diligence)

I looked google and youtube they explain the concept but NOT the Engineering/Decision choice or necessity to use a dedicated heap for dynamic alloc.

It could be that Dynamic alloc is not possible with stacks. Please point to an article I will search meanwhile.

Guys Found A stackoverflow post similar to this one as I'm typing. But since I already typed, I will post this. :*

Warm thanks,,,Happy Coding

Regards,,,
Wulv

Comment: Stacks work fine if you always want to deallocate objects in the reverse order of their allocation (LIFO).  But what if you don't want that?

Comment: NB: I replace a tag, since [tag:heap] has nothing to do with memory allocation.

Comment: Actually after doing my homework. It turned that dync mem alloc heap is not an actual heap DS. They just simply coincidentally have the same name.